# Redirecting after displaying information

Tags: html, user-interface, redirect, header

Let's say the user submits feedback, and I want to redirect them to another location afterwards. Is it okay to do the following?

```
header("Refresh: 4; url=$location");
header("Connection: close");

echo
    "
    Feedback successfully submitted.

    <hr />
    ";
```

Is there any other way of displaying information *before* redirecting? Should I use `<meta http-equiv="refresh"`... in this case?

Comment: why would you display information before submitting? why not afterwards? header('Location: youpage.php'); can redirect you to other page. If you need to display information before submitting, you have to use jquery or ajax depending on your need.

Comment: It displays it AFTER submitting, but before redirecting to other page. So, without javascript it is impossible to do somehting like this?

Comment: Oh.. my bad... Yes, you can do something like this: <?php header("Refresh: 10;url=http://www.yourdestination.com/"); ?>. You may not need to use the meta refresh..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean something like this

http://zazeni.si/projekti/izrisitakoj/main/vprasanje_oddano

In my opinion you got it right, just use

```
<p>Thank you for submitting. If you're not redirected in 5 seconds, click <a href="redirect.php">here</a> </p>

<?php header( "refresh:5;url=redirect.php");  ?>
```

Comment: Great...it does seemingly work. I just hope this doesn't have any security issues

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not really a security expert. Maybe Google it a bit.